# Div CSS not working

Tags: css, html

My CSS to set the background works,but my css for the div .about doesn't.

This is my HTML Sheet:

```
   <DOCTYPE! HTML>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="About"
    <p>Hi</p>
    </div>
    </body>
```

This is my CSS Sheet

```
body {
    background-image: url("BG.jpg");
    background-repeat: repeat-repeat;
}
.About{font-size:24px;
color:#ffffff;
background-color:#000000;
padding:50px;
margin:50px;}
}
```

The Body tag works,but the rest doesn't.

I've also tried this

```
body {
    background-image: url("BG.jpg");
    background-repeat: repeat-repeat;
}
.About{font-size:24px;
color:#ffffff;
background-color:#000000;
padding:50px;
margin:50px;}
}
p.About{font-size:24px;
color:#ffffff;
background-color:#000000;
padding:50px;
margin:50px;
}
```

And that doesn't work at all.
And this.

```
body {
    background-image: url("BG.jpg");
    background-repeat: repeat-repeat;
}
.About{font-size:24px;
color:#ffffff;
background-color:#000000;
padding:50px;
margin:50px;}
}
p.About{font-size:24px;
color:#ffffff;
background-color:#000000;
padding:50px;
margin:50px;
}
p{font-size:24px;
color:#ffffff;
background-color:#000000;
padding:50px;
margin:50px;

}
```

The "p" tag works,but applies it in a way that's to general.I need it to apply specifically to the "About" Div.

I've tested it both Google Chrome and Internet Explorer-so I dont think its the browser acting odd.
Any idea what the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

You need to enclose the tag

```
<div class="About"> ... </div>
```

and on CSS, you have an extra `}` .

It should be:

```
.About{font-size:24px;
color:#ffffff;
background-color:#000000;
padding:50px;
margin:50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You have a number of syntax errors which will cause unexpected behaviour and one of your rules is incorrect.**

1. You have not closed your `div` correctly which could lead to the browser misinterpreting the markup
2. In the `.About` rule you have an extra `}` after  `margin: 50px;` which may lead to rules being ignored
3. The rule `p.About` will attempt to target a `p` tag which has the class `.About`. Given your markup you want `.About p` which will target any `p` tags in an element with the class `.About`

Given you are specifically trying to target the `p` in the `.About` `div` the only rule you need is `.About p` (the `.About` and `p` rules are not necessary).

```css
body {
  background-image: url("BG.jpg");
  background-repeat: repeat-repeat;
}
.About p {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 50px;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="About">
  <p>Hi</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly enclose the div tag:

```
<div class="About">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class = "About">
    <p>Hi</p>
</div>
```

instead of

```
<div class="About"
    <p>Hi</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have an extra '}' in CSS and properly enclose your div

```
<div class = "about">.. </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

firstly enclose tag

```
<div class="About"> ... </div>
```

Now it should be

```
.About{font-size:24px;
color:#ffffff;
background-color:#000000;
padding:50px;
margin:50px;
}
```